# File written by Android SAF has the tail of the original version

Tags: android, android-11, storage-access-framework

I made an app [Tiddloid](https://github.com/donmor/Tiddloid) and it runs well on my phone (a Meizu with an os based on Android 8.1). It saves modified html files to the original file using the following code:

```
...
                try (ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                        OutputStream os = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri)) {
                    if (os == null)
                        throw new FileNotFoundException(MainActivity.EXCEPTION_SAF_FILE_NOT_EXISTS);
                    int len = is.available();
                    int length, lengthTotal = 0;
                    byte[] b = new byte[MainActivity.BUF_SIZE];
                    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                        os.write(b, 0, length);
                        lengthTotal += length;
                    }
                    os.flush();
                    if (lengthTotal != len)
                        throw new IOException(MainActivity.EXCEPTION_TRANSFER_CORRUPTED);
                    failed = false;
                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        if (tree != null && treeIndex != null) try {
                            syncTree(tree, id, treeIndex);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        getInfo(wv);
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(TWEditorWV.this, R.string.failed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    failed = true;
                    dumpOnFail(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), uri);
                }
...
```

Several weeks ago I'm testing it on an Android 11 AVD. I noticed that sometimes there are html codes at the end of the saved file, especially if the new file to be saved is smaller than original:

```
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO   <- this is the original
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX      <- this is the new file
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXOOO   <- the actual saved file
```

At that time I treated it as a bug of AVD, because this had never happened to other AVDs and my phone. But these days more and more people's posting issues on GitHub, complaining that the same thing's happening. Anyone have idea about this? I even made it throw exceptions if detected that written size not equal to the source bytearray, but it never throws, just making the file corrupted.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: added a part of code for saving